# Flowgear Quick Map Results an array typed values in JSON object

Tags: json, integration, flowgear

[image]

I am trying to send a json payload like below

> {
> "type": "test",
> "subject": "Testing email",
> "message": "Email Notification Services Test.",
> "recipient": [
> "test",
> "test"
> ],
> "attachment": ""
> }

and I need a payload in the output as

> {
> "type": "test",
> "subject": "Testing email",
> "message": "Email Notification Services Test.",
> "recipient": [
> "asda",
> "test"
> ],
> "attachment": ""
> }

but I am getting payload as

> {
> "type": [
> "test"
> ],
> "subject": [
> "Testing email"
> ],
> "message": [
> "Email Notification Services Test."
> ],
> "recipient": [
> "test",
> "test"
> ],
> "attachment": [
> ""
> ]
> }

I don't understand why every value is added in the form of an array in the output. Can somebody help me with this?
Using Flowgear I am using Quick Map connector to get this output. Can somebody help me with this? Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `FIRST()` function.

[image: Usage of FIRST() function]